# Web server URL rewriting. Server Fault or Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault

I see lots of questions about [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine). I am tempted to start closing these as *belongs on Server Fault.

Is URL rewriting a developer or server administrator task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what kind. In the Apache/PHP world I understand it's more of a configuration setting and might mean getting a system administrator involved. But even here, it's usually something the programmer does. In the [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) world, it's more likely a code change that the programmer has to make.

Answer (score 2):

It usually involves writing regular expressions - I count that as programming.